# Why is my solution to the exact ODE not coming out right?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE and I'm trying to figure out whether or not it's exact, and for the most part I *think* I'm doing okay, but then I have to implicitly differentiate at the end to check my solution, and no matter what I do I am still missing a term.

$$(1)\;\;\; {t\over y}dy+(1+\ln y)dt=0$$
$$(2)\;\;\;f_y(y,t)={t\over y} ;\\f_t(y,t)=1+\ln y$$
Integrate (1) with respect to $y$
$$f(y,t)=t\ln y+h(t)$$
Take derivative with respect to $t$ 
$$f_t(y,t)=\ln y+h'(t)$$
Integrate $h'(t): \int h'(t)dt=\int 1dt=t$

Plug $h(t)$ back into $f(y,t)$
$$f(y,t)=t \ln y+t$$
Set equal to $C$ to get the solution:
$$t \ln y+t=C$$

Now I need to check the solution by implicitly differentiating
$$t \ln y+t-C=0$$ Where $C$ is an arbitrary constant

Differentiate with respect to $t$
$${d\over dt}t \ln y+{d\over dt}t-{d\over dt}C=0$$
$$\ln y+1=0$$
So I'm just missing ${t\over y}$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is fine. Setting
$$
f(t,y)=t\ln y+t=c
$$
and differentiating you get
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy=0\implies
(\ln y+1)\mathrm dt+\frac{t}{y}\mathrm dy=0
$$
as was required and constructed.

In fact, you can solve for $y$ explicitly, 
$$
y(t)=e^{\frac{c}{t}-1}
$$